# R: Using paste depending on the number of words in a string within a function

Tags: r, string, conditional-statements, paste

I have a list where each list component has one string vector. Each string vector is of length 1 and contains one or more words separated with spaces (the original list is much larger):

```
> f <- list("one", "two three", "four", "five six seven")
> f
[[1]]
[1] "one"

[[2]]
[1] "two three"

[[3]]
[1] "four"

[[4]]
[1] "five six seven"
```

What I need to do is to paste strings before and after the string in each component depending on whether it contains one or more words. The result I look for is something like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Single number: one."

[[2]]
[1] "Multiple numbers: two three."

[[3]]
[1] "Single number: four."

[[4]]
[1] "Multiple numbers: five six seven."
```

I tried the following, counting the number of words in each string with `str_count` from the `stringr` package:

```
x <- lapply(f, function(j) {
  if(str_count(string = f[[j]], pattern = "\\S+") == 1) {
    xx[[j]] <- paste("Single number: ", f[[j]], ".", sep = "")
  } else {
    xx[[j]] <- paste("Multiple numbers: ", f[[j]], ".", sep = "")
  }
  })
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in if (str_count(string = f[[j]], pattern = "\\S+") == 1) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f[[j]]` can be used when we are indexing the elements of list i.e.  `lapply(seq_along(f),..`, but here we are looping on `f` itself.  So, just do `str_count(j,..)`

```
library(stringr)
lapply(f, function(j) {
                        if(str_count(j, '\\S+') >1) {
                            paste("Multiple numbers: ", j, '.', sep="") 
                          } else paste("Single number: ", j, ".", sep="") 
                       })
#[[1]]
#[1] "Single number: one."

#[[2]]
#[1] "Multiple numbers: two three."

#[[3]]
#[1] "Single number: four."

#[[4]]
#[1] "Multiple numbers: five six seven."
```

NOTE: This could be done without using any external packages too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still getting confused with indexes in functions.

Comment: @panman You can look at the output of `lapply(seq_along(f), function(i) i)` and `lapply(f, function(x) x)`
`

Comment: If I understand correctly, the first solution you are pointing to returns numerical indexes of the sequence of the list components, while the second returns the components themselves. I learned many new things today :)

Comment: @panman Yes, you are correct.  In your post, you were trying to index the list components with the list element itself (which is character).

Comment: I see. Still in the beginning stage. Thanks a lot for clarifying these for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of R’s vectorisation to simplify this; however, this requires using a *vector* as an input instead of a list — which is OK in your example:

```
f = unlist(f)
prefix = ifelse(str_count(f, '\\S+') > 1, 'Multiple words: ', 'Single word: ')
paste0(prefix, f, '.')
```

Comment: Thanks! Will certainly use it in other situations.

Answer (score 2):

Given a string the function `prefix` produces either `"Multiple number:"` or `"Single Number:"`.   `lapply` it to every component of `f` and then use `Map` to paste the corresponding prefixes and `f` components together.  No packages are used:

```
prefix <- function(x) if (any(grepl(" ", x))) "Multiple numbers:" else "Single number:"
Map(paste, lapply(f, prefix), f)
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Single number: one"

[[2]]
[1] "Multiple numbers: two three"

[[3]]
[1] "Single number: four"

[[4]]
[1] "Multiple numbers: five six seven"
```

The last line could alternately be written like this:

```
as.list(paste(sapply(f, prefix), f))
```

and if its not important that the result be a list then `as.list` could be omitted.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Simple and efficient solution.